# Filling Sidebar Implementation with Rails and Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

This is mostly an implementation question for a webapp I'm trying to develop. I'm relatively inexperienced so I want to check if my idea for implementation is decent or if there's a much easier way.

#### The Problem

I want to create a scrollable sidebar that automatically fills with small containers that hold a user profile photo and their name. The basic idea is that a user is a member of a class and the sidebar should hold all of their classmates. The sidebar should be a fixed size and the user should be able scroll down through their classmates and click on a user if they want visit their page.

#### My Ideas For Implementing

It seems to me that I will need to use some embedded ruby to direct the filling process. Some psuedocode would be something along the lines of "For every user in this class, create a container with their picture and name". I haven't given a lot of thought as to actually handle this step but I'm mostly concerned with the actual html structure.

My idea is to do something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <!-- for each user in class -->
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span">
                            <!-- Load appropriate user data -->
</div> where appropriate...
```

Is this the "proper" way to go about implenting this? I haven't been able to find much information on the idea and visit an example site's source code isn't all that helpful as the sidebar is already filled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate your sidebar HTML and logic into a partial, E.g. "app/views/shared/_sidebar.html.erb".  From there on, you can accept a collection of data from whatever view you're rendering.

#### View file

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <%= render "shared/sidebar", collection: @users %>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Sidebar partial

```
<div class="span2">
  .....
    <% @users.classmates.each do |e| %>
      <%= e.name %>
    <% end %>
  .....
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Does the basic logic make sense for filling the sidebar though? Also, are you familiar with getting the sidebar to scroll? I don't think a basic container will just do it one it's own and I haven't been able to find anything on the twitter bootstrap site to help...

Comment: Getting a sidebar (div) to scroll requires basic CSS knowledge.  If you're unsure about those concepts, I'd suggest ditching Rails and back-end development until you get a full grasp on HTML and CSS.

Comment: I'll look into it. I was in the middle of working out that basic html and css but then I wanted to pick up Rails as well. Thanks for the help though.